# ¿Como hacer la llamada a este metodo?

Tags: java

intento hacer la invocacion de este metodo en el menu pero en la parte donde dice "buscarProducto(lista, codigo);" me marca un error mas que nada en la parte de la palabra "codigo", pero no se cual sea

```
switch(opcion) {
            case 1:
                procesarArchivo();
                break;
            case 2:
                buscarProducto(lista, codigo);
                break;
            case 3:
                
                break;
            case 4:
                
                break;
            case 5:
                
                break;
            case 6:
                salir = true;
                break;
            }
```

ese es el metodo a invocar:

```
public static int buscarProducto(LinkedList lista, String codigo) {
        Operaciones operaciones = new Operaciones();
        int posicion;
        
        posicion =operaciones.buscarProducto(lista, codigo);
        return posicion;
    }
```

y en otra clase coloque este metodo tambien:

```
public int buscarProducto(LinkedList listaProducto,String codigo) {
        int posicion = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<listaProducto.size(); i++) {
            Producto prod = (Producto)listaProducto.get(i);
            if(prod.getCodigo().compareTo(codigo)==0) {
                posicion = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return posicion;
    }
```

Comment: Que error te da

Comment: "codigo cannot be resolved to a variable" eso es lo que me marca como error

Comment: Hola, en el switch, asegurate que en `case 2: buscarProducto(lista, codigo);  break;` la variable `codigo` esté inicializada o declarada. Por el error que comentas la palabra "codigo" en si no es una variable. Quizas no la hayas declarado mas arriba. Si puedes compartir más código sería máa facil ayudarte. Tambien agrega el error tal cual te aparece dentro de tu pregunta